# have versus having

Tags: verb-forms

I was wondering if someone could help me with the self-made scenario bellow and tell me which choice fits grammatically better in the blank and why:

> - He was supposed to invest 500,000 US dollars, but when it came to payment, he said something that made me fall into doubt. after he said that I started to ..... second thoughts.

a) have

b) having

Comment: **start(ed)** can be complemented by the *to*-marked infinitive or by the -ing form of the verb. He **started having** second thoughts.  He **started to have** second thoughts.

Comment: I wonder if it is helpful to use such a linguistically marked term for a beginner. Start and begin take the notional form (infinitive) or the ing form without to. I just think that's simpler.